# how to add icon inside textbox without changing width of the textbox

Tags: jquery, textbox, icons

I need to include 'X' icon inside text box to clear the text box value.

While Text in entered I am adding an icon, this will increase text box width and looking odd.

EDIT: `<div id="searchArea">
        <input type="text" id="search"/>
        <span class="fa-close" id="clear-search"></span>
        <span class="fa-search"></span>
    </div>`

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#search", function(e) {
if ($("#search").val() != "") {
    $("#clear-search").css("display", "block");
} else {
    $("#clear-search").css("display", "none");
}
```

});

Suggest me how to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you please add some HTML as well?

Comment: Please see the Edit. I have added html.

Comment: Hmm, I can't find anything wrong with the code: [fiddle][1][1]: https://jsfiddle.net/Zorken17/3wgpdmd3/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe :

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#search", function(e) {
if ($("#search").val() != "") {
    $("#clear-search").css("display", "inline-block");
} else {
    $("#clear-search").css("display", "none");
}
});
```

Or

You can do display:block and modify the CSS in float or absolute position. Give me a fiddle if possible.

Comment: inline-block is not working. I am getting same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I use for a search clear in bootstrap with the icon made with glyphicon:

JS:

```
$(".input-sm").addClass("searchinput");
$(".input-sm" ).wrap( "<div class='form-group wrapsearchinput'>" );

$(".searchinput").after( "<span id='searchclear' class='searchclear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span>" ); 

$(".searchinput").keyup(function () {
    $(this).next().toggle(Boolean($(this).val()));
});
$(".searchclear").toggle(Boolean($(".searchinput").val()));
$(".searchclear").click(function () {
    $('.dataTables_filter input').val('').keyup();
});
```

CSS:

```
.searchinput {
    width: 200px;
}
.searchclear {
    position:absolute !important;
    right:5px;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:14px;
    margin:auto;
}
```